# catkin_make: No module named 'catkin_pkg'

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am getting the following error and is unable to remove the same.

```
#### Running command: "make cmake_check_build_system" in "/home/csio/catkin_ws/build"
####
-- Using CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX: /home/csio/catkin_ws/devel
-- Using CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /opt/ros/melodic
-- This workspace overlays: /opt/ros/melodic
-- Found PythonInterp: /usr/bin/python3 (found suitable version "3.6.8", minimum required is "2") 
-- Using PYTHON_EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/python3
-- Using Debian Python package layout
-- Using empy: /usr/bin/empy
-- Using CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING: ON
-- Call enable_testing()
-- Using CATKIN_TEST_RESULTS_DIR: /home/csio/catkin_ws/build/test_results
-- Found gtest sources under '/usr/src/googletest': gtests will be built
-- Found gmock sources under '/usr/src/googletest': gmock will be built
--Found PythonInterp: /usr/bin/python3 (found version "3.6.8") 
-- Using Python nosetests: /usr/bin/nosetests-2.7
ImportError: "from catkin_pkg.package import parse_package" failed: No module named 'catkin_pkg'
Make sure that you have installed "catkin_pkg", it is up to date and on the PYTHONPATH.
CMake Error at /opt/ros/melodic/share/catkin/cmake/safe_execute_process.cmake:11 (message):
  execute_process(/usr/bin/python3
  "/opt/ros/melodic/share/catkin/cmake/parse_package_xml.py"
  "/opt/ros/melodic/share/catkin/cmake/../package.xml"
  "/home/csio/catkin_ws/build/catkin/catkin_generated/version/package.cmake")
  returned error code 1
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/ros/melodic/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_package_xml.cmake:74 (safe_execute_process)
  /opt/ros/melodic/share/catkin/cmake/all.cmake:168 (_catkin_package_xml)
  /opt/ros/melodic/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:20 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:56 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/csio/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/csio/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
Makefile:320: recipe for target 'cmake_check_build_system' failed
make: *** [cmake_check_build_system] Error 1
Invoking "make cmake_check_build_system" failed
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/340510/catkin_make:-no-module-named-%27catkin_pkg%27/) by [shashi](https://answers.ros.org/users/50434/shashi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 43 on 2019-12-21

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Install catkin_pkg using below command

```
sudo apt-get install python-catkin-pkg
```

You have to verify that the catkin_pkg is installed into python 3 directory. If below command didn't work, try

```
pip3 install catkin_pkg
```

Make sure you have installed pip for running above command

---

Originally posted by [Abhishekpg](https://answers.ros.org/users/50018/abhishekpg/) with karma: 195 on 2019-12-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-12-22**:
No, please don't suggest people to use `pip` to install ROS Python dependencies. It's unnecessary and `pip` packages are not automatically updated as you circumvent the system's package manager.

There is one exception to this and that would be to install those packages for Python interpreters other than the system default.

But in that case please always mention the downsides, as it has plenty.

**Comment by [Abhishekpg](https://answers.ros.org/users/50018/abhishekpg/) on 2019-12-22**:
Ok understood. Can you please tell how to change the python interpreter.

**Comment by [shashi](https://answers.ros.org/users/50434/shashi/) on 2019-12-22**:
On running the above suggestion, I received this error:

Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/catkin_pkg'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.

**Comment by [Abhishekpg](https://answers.ros.org/users/50018/abhishekpg/) on 2019-12-23**:
Try adding `--user` at the end of the command

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is most likely your problem:

> ```
> -- Found PythonInterp: /usr/bin/python3 (found suitable version "3.6.8", minimum required is "2")
> ```

```
-- Using PYTHON_EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/python3
...
-- Found PythonInterp: /usr/bin/python3 (found version "3.6.8")
```

Note how it says: Python 3 is found and used.

The Debian packages provided by the ROS buildfarm for Melodic are only installed for the default system provided Python interpreter. On Ubuntu Bionic (which you are most likely running, seeing as you tagged with `melodic`) that would still be Python 2.

As the Python 3 interpreter is found instead, none of the required Python packages are installed for it and this results in the error you show.

You'll either have to install `catkin_pkg` (and a few others) for the Python 3 interpreter (using the `pip3` command shown by @Abhishekpg ), or make sure Catkin uses the Python 2 interpreter.

My recommendation would be the latter, as the rest of Melodic will also have been built against Python 2. Not Python 3.

The next release of ROS 1 (Noetic) will support Python 3.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-12-22

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [shashi](https://answers.ros.org/users/50434/shashi/) on 2019-12-22**:
How do I make sure that Catkin uses Python 2 interpreter? Is there a workaround?

**Comment by [everything](https://answers.ros.org/users/66620/everything/) on 2020-12-28**:
In my case, I had to install `sudo apt install python-pip` and `sudo apt install python3-pip` and it automatically chose the right pip (Python 2.7 or 3.6) during installation. Perhaps you can even leave out python3-pip installation, but it does not harm at least. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63448467/installing-opencv-fails-because-it-cannot-find-skbuild/65479652#65479652.